# UI Convention: Shortcut key for application exit?

Tags: user-interface, conventions

Is there a convention for the shortcut keys for application exit?

Some applications uses `Alt+X` some others use `Ctrl+ X` and `Ctrl+Q`.
Applications like FF and IE doesnot assign a shortcut at all.

So is there any accepted convention for that?

Note:Am talking about Windows here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that of your three suggestions, I'd stay away from `Alt+X`, since that would often refer to whichever menu had `X` as its accelerator key, and `Ctrl+X` because that's usually Cut. Beyond that... I don't know.

Microsoft apps don't seem to define one, probably because you can just `Alt+F4` out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of supported shortcuts...

http://www.computerhope.com/shortcut/windows.htm

It appears that Alt+F4 or Ctrl+F4 are your best bet.  Also, Ctrl+W closes the current window in IE but also works for Explorer and other Windows windows. :)